# Heroku Create Function Not Working in Git Bash Terminal on Windows

Tags: heroku

When I type 'heroku login' at my git bash terminal (in Windows), I get a successful login message. Then, when I type 'heroku create' the terminal hangs and nothing happens. Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Comment: have you found solution about this @Xenilo

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...when I use git bash in Windows to log into heroku, it doesn't provide a prompt back. I had to kill the login process with ctrl-c, and then I was able to create using 'heroku create.'